# Why is the memory address the same every time you enter the same function?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm debugging a piece of code.Every time I debug into that function, I found that the data memory address is the same.

I have tried to explain  it. What confuses me is that every time I jump out of this function, the memory allocated on the stack is freed, so why is it the same?

```
QList<int> PixMapVsImage::getIntList()
{
    QList<int> list;
    list << 1 << 2;
    qDebug() << (&list) ;
    qDebug() << (&list.at(0));
    return list;
}
```

[image: stack addresses]

I Really don't konw why the memory allocation address is the same? So I really don't konw what the actual result is.

Comment: Restart your machine and try it again and see if it is identical again.  My hunch is that your machine grabs the first available memory, which happens to be the same section.  A restart will shuffle enough things that it might not grab the same memory.

Comment: It's a coincidence that it's the same, happens often but there is no guarantee it will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the address of a local variable reflects the depth of the call stack. If the function is called in the same sequence each time, then it's not surprising that its local variables land on the same spot.

Now, elements of the list are likely allocated on the heap. A typical heap implementation would maintain a list of recently deallocated blocks (a [free list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list)). If you allocate `N` bytes from the heap, then deallocate them, then allocate `N` bytes again, chances are high you'll get the same block back, off the top of the free list. This may be what you observe.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But I really have tried several times, the address of the local variable of list is the same.I think it could be something  relationship with copy with write.